# Jackson serialize a key for items within an array

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a couple java classes, the first is a container for instances of the second. The container class has an id and a list of items, like:

```
    public class Container {
      String id = "123";
      ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
     ...
    }
```

and the Item class like:

```
    public class Item {
       String id = "123123";
       String notes = "what a day";
      ...
    }
```

When I serialize it, I get something like:

```
   { "id" : "123",
     "items" : [ {
       "id" : "123123",
       "notes" : "what a day"
      }, {
       "id" : "456456",
       "notes" : "what a night"
      }
      ]
  }
```

But, what I want is:

```
    {
        "id": "123",
        "items": [
            {
             "123123": [
                {
                "notes": "what a day"
                }
             ],
             "456456": [
                {
                "notes": "what a night"
                }
             ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

where the "id" from the Item class is the identifier for the elements in the "items" array.
How would the java class structure change, or what directives would be given to jackson to achieve the desired structure?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://jsonlint.com/

As JSON is a set of `name/value` pairs you will get this error

```
Parse error on line 4:
...: [        "123123": {            "not
----------------------^
Expecting '}', ',', ']'
```

If you want to have dynamic `keys` for the `name/value` pairs you could always write out the JSON in your program logic (Not Jackson)

Comment: Great catch - I corrected the example for what I really want.

Comment: so you want to have the name of the name/value pair being dynamic? If so I have updated my answer